# Django реализация теста

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, form, django-model

подскажите как реализовать добавление теста через формы , что бы можно было добавлять вопросы и к ним варианты ответов

models.py

```
class Tests(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField('Question',  blank=True, )
    max_points = models.FloatField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('test',kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

        
class Question(models.Model):
    # test = models.ForeignKey(Tests, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return " {} , Тест {} ".format(self.title,self.test.title)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail',kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=4096)
    points = models.FloatField(default=1)
    lock_other = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.title,self.question)


class Answer(models.Model):
    # user = models.ForeignKey('Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice = models.ForeignKey(Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice.title


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=500,null=True, blank=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    create_test = models.ForeignKey(Tests,null=True,blank=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    complete = models.ManyToManyField(Tests,  blank=True, related_name='complete')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

view.py

```
class CreateTest(CreateView):
    model = Tests
    form_class = AddTestForm
    template_name='addtest.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        test = form.save(commit=False)
        test.owner = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        test.save()
        return redirect('/add/question/')


class CreateQuestion(CreateView):
    model = Question
    form_class = formset_factory(AddquestionsForm) 
    template_name='addtest.html'


# class CreateQuestion(CreateView):
#     model = Question
#     form_class = formset_factory(AddquestionsForm) 
#     template_name='addtest.html'
```

forms.py

```
class AddTestForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=Tests
        fields=('title',)


class AddquestionsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['title',]


class AddchoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ('title','points',)
```

Comment: получилось проверить?

Comment: Это не совсем то , там по 1 полю , мне нужно для каждого теста создавать много вопросов допустим нажимать + и получать новое поля для вопроса и так же для вариантов, а такими формами выводит только по 1 полю

Answer (score 2):

1. Делаете формы, для ваших моделей, например:

```
# forms.py
class AddquestionsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ['question', 'title', 'points', 'lock_other']
```

2. Делаете ссылку и всьюшку для ваших форм:

```
# views.py
def get_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddquestionsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse('/thanks/')
    else:
        form = AddquestionsForm()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('add_questions', views.get_name),
]
```

3. Также делаете html которий будет отображать форму

```
{{ html | safe }}
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">Присоедениться</button>
</form>
```

4. Переходите по урлу - вуоля, форма готова. Заполняете - ответы сохраняются в БД

Ссылка на официальную документацию:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/